# Issue related to creating NetworkInterface in ApolloClient

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I need to make my own request to graphql endpoint. (The default implementation makes POST call to the url that we specify). I need to make a AJAX call. I read it from:
http://dev.apollodata.com/core/network.html#custom-network-interface

It clearly specifies that I need to create a NetworkInterface and pass it to ApolloClient.

I did something like this:

```
const customInterface = {
    query(request) {
        return $.post(url_of_graphql_endpoint)
            .send({query : request.query.loc.source.body})
            .end()
            .then(result => result.text)    
    }
}

const client = new ApolloClient({networkInterface: customInterface});

ReactDOM.render((
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={App} />
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

The network request is being made to the graphql endpoint and the server also responds with the apt response (that it is supposed to send).

Even after this, I am getting some error in my browser because of which I am not able to display the data that is fetched from my server. The component is always in 'loading' state.

```
Error in observer.error 
Error
    at new ApolloError (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:22220:23)
    at <URL>:12345/bundle.js:21680:39
    at <URL>:12345/bundle.js:22168:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at <URL>:12345/bundle.js:22165:27
    at <URL>:12345/bundle.js:81569:11
    at baseForOwn (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:47066:20)
    at forOwn (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:82561:20)
    at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:22163:9)
    at Array.<anonymous> (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:21595:23)
    at dispatch (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:56461:19)
    at <URL>:12345/bundle.js:64699:30
    at Object.dispatch (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:17264:16)
    at <URL>:12345/bundle.js:22130:33
    at tryCatcher (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:7247:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:5269:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:5326:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:5371:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:5446:18)
    at <URL>:12345/bundle.js:2169:25
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (<URL>:12345/bundle.js:6501:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do override the functionality of query method and so I am only posting the answer for others who might face the same issue.

The way I tried to override the query method is wrong. I did it like this.

```
class CustomNetworkInterface extends HttpNetworkInterface{
    query(request){
                return $.post(url_of_graphql_endpoint)
            .send({query : request.query.loc.source.body})
            .end()
            .then(result => result.text)    
    }
}
```

For making the ApolloClient, just pass in the object of CustomNetworkInterface.

```
const client = new ApolloClient({networkInterface: new CustomNetworkInterface(http://url)});

ReactDOM.render((
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={App} />
    </Router>
  </ApolloProvider>
  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```